# Problemas com python 3

Tags: python, tkinter

Boa noite!

Estou tendo um pequeno problema com python 3.x no meu linux mint 19.03

---

Código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*-coding: utf-8-*-
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
def msg():
  m = val.get()
  Label(win, text=m).pack()      
win.geometry("250x250+250+250")
win.title("aula excript")
val = Entry(win).pack()      
Button(win, text="ok", command=msg).pack()      
win.mainloop()
```

O código acima, está gerando a seguinte exceção:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "./tt.py", line 6, in msg
    m = val.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Agradeço desde já =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro ocorre, pois você está inserindo o retorno do método `pack` na variável `val`, sendo que `pack` não possui um retorno (None):

```
val = Entry(win).pack()
```

Gerando assim o erro:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

---

Quando na verdade, `val` deveria conter apenas o retorno de `Entry`, e com esse valor então, chamar o método `pack`:

```
val = Entry(win)
val.pack()
```

Com isso, o método `get` vai retornar o valor corretamente, deixando de ocorrer o erro.

---

Seu código então, ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*-coding: utf-8-*-

from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

def msg():
  m = val.get()
  Label(win, text=m).pack()

win.geometry("250x250+250+250")
win.title("aula excript")
val = Entry(win)
val.pack()
Button(win, text="ok", command=msg).pack()      
win.mainloop()
```